# auto generated constructor Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am not seeing the auto generate constructor option in android studio with Kotlin . With Java I was used to make auto generate constructor to all fields .
Is there an option for this in Kotlin ?
Thanks .

Comment: Show your class (example), please... But here's a hint: Java != Kotlin — you have to get used to new languages...

Comment: every class without a constructor has an empty default constructor without need of writing it. What is your point.

Comment: Goto code use alt + insert and create Secondary Constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Kotlin code currently looks like this:

> ```
> class Weapon(type: String, damage: Int) {
>     ...
> }
> ```

Everything inside the parentheses following the class name **is** your constructor. You already have a constructor, so there's no need to "generate" anything!

If you want to be able to retain these constructor arguments as properties, prepend the `val` or `var` keyword to them:

```
class Weapon(val type: String, val damage: Int) {
    ...
}
```

Note that you can **optionally** use the `constructor` keyword to make it very explicit:

```
class Weapon constructor(val type: String, val damage: Int)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can able to see this in android studio. 
Go to Android studio -> Code >> Generate >> click on **Secondary Constructor**